# Is the Ukraine Transcript word for word?

Tags: donald-trump, ukraine, trump-impeachment

When I google "Ukraine transcript" first result that shows up is [a PDF hosted on whitehouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Unclassified09.2019.pdf). Is this transcript a word-for-word replication of the phone call that took place between President Trump and President Zelenskyy of the Ukraine?

The document has a heading: "MEMORANDUM OF TELEPHONE CONVERSATION".

Comment: Ah interesting. I wasn't sure that was referencing the same transcript since I saw some headlines that the 'full transcript was released'

Comment: Unfortunately many people - including Trump - keep referring to that document as a transcript, despite the fact it explicitly states it is "not a verbatim transcript".

Comment: Document says: "CAUTION: A Memorandum of a Telephone Conversation.·(TELCON) is not a verbatim transcript of a discussion. The text in this document records the notes and recollections of Situation Room Duty Officers and-NSC policy staff assigned to listen and memorialize the conversation in written form as the conversation takes place. A number of factors can affect the accuracy of the record, including poor telecommunications connections and variations in accent and/or interpretation. The word "inaudible" is used to indicate portions of a conversation that the notetaker was unable to hear."

Comment: As well, "“Don’t rely on whatever transcript is released,” said a former staffer, who spoke on the condition of anonymity to comment candidly. “Even if it’s unredacted; those transcripts are heavily edited by political leadership at NSC. I’ve seen substance deleted from these call ‘transcripts’ to delete either superfluous details or more substance.”